# I want to query a json file to find users with two or more tags in common

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "c++",
        "jquery",
        "css",
        "html"
      ],
      "name": "John Doe",
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "vb",
        "css"
      ],
      "name": "Bill Gates",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "c++",
        "css",
        "html"
      ],
      "name": "Steve Jobs",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to return only users who match Tags twice or more, for instance:

John Doe and Steve Jobs have c++ and css in common.

I was trying to achieve this by performing tons of for statements but I don't think this is the best solution.

That's what I have so far:

```c#
JObject res = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:/json/data.json"));
int jsonLength = res["users"].Count();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++)
{
    string name = res["users"][i]["name"].ToString();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(res["users"][i]["id"]);
    string tags = res["users"][i]["tags"].ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
    Console.WriteLine("Tags: " + tags);
}
```

I saw some people querying a json file like they do in SQL but I've never used LINQ before so I have no idea on how it works also I'm not sure what's the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a list of all users that share two or more tags with another user, you could do something like this:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\json\data.json");
JArray users = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["users"];

// Generate pair-wise combinations of users
// and check for intersection of their tags.
// If two or more common tags, add both users to a hash set

HashSet<JObject> result = new HashSet<JObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    JObject user1 = (JObject)users[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < users.Count; j++)
    {
        JObject user2 = (JObject)users[j];
        if (user1["tags"].Select(t => t.ToString())
            .Intersect(user2["tags"].Select(t => t.ToString()))
            .Count() > 1)
        {
            result.Add(user1);
            result.Add(user2);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("All users that share two or more tags with another user:");
Console.WriteLine();

foreach (JObject user in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + user["id"]);
    Console.WriteLine("name: " + user["name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("tags: " + string.Join(", ", user["tags"]));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IpZBIR

---

If you want to see each pair of users along with the common tags between them, you need a little more code to capture the pairings.  First, I would create a couple of classes to make the data easier to work with:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}

class Pairing
{
    public User User1 { get; set; }
    public User User2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> CommonTags { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can capture the pairings like this:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\json\data.json");

// Parse the JSON into a list of Users

List<User> users = JObject.Parse(json)["users"]
   .Select(t => t.ToObject<User>())
   .ToList();

// Generate pair-wise combinations of users
// and check for intersection of their tags.
// If two or more common tags, add the pairing to a list

List<Pairing> pairings = new List<Pairing>();
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    User user1 = users[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < users.Count; j++)
    {
        User user2 = users[j];
        var commonTags = user1.Tags.Intersect(user2.Tags).ToList();

        if (commonTags.Count > 1)
        {
            pairings.Add(new Pairing
            {
                User1 = user1,
                User2 = user2,
                CommonTags = commonTags
            });
        }
    }
}

// Write out the results

Console.WriteLine("Pairs of users sharing two or more tags with each other:");
Console.WriteLine();

foreach (Pairing p in pairings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} (id {1}) and {2} (id {3}) have ({4}) in common.",
     p.User1.Name, p.User1.Id, p.User2.Name, p.User2.Id, string.Join(", ", p.CommonTags)));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vQlJSV

Comment: Awesome man. Thank you so much!!! One more thing, it's possible to use this logic to group the names on the same line as well? For instance:

output:

Name: John Doe, Steve Jobs
Tags: c++, css

Have a great day :D

Comment: Something like a group by.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  You want all user names on one line?  Or you want each pair of users on a line with the common tags for that pair?  Or something else?

Comment: I want each pair of users on a line with the common tags for that pair.

Comment: You're a genius man. Thank you so much!!! Yesterday I spend around six hours trying to figure this out using 'for's all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You should create below model per your posted JSON (use http://json2csharp.com/). Deserialize your JSON string to `RootObject` and then you can use LINQ query to filter the data per your requirement

```
public class User
{
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I generated the classes using the website that you mentioned but how do I Deserialize my Json to a string ?

I'm using the following line to get info from my json:

JObject res = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:/json/data.json"));

Answer (score 1):

Create an `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a class to hold the JSON data:

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now proceed to deserialize the JSON:

```
string json = "....";
ResponseData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeJson<ResponseData>(json);
IEnumerable<User> users = data.Users;
```

Then, to find users with a common tag, you can create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<User> WithTag(this IEnumerable<User> users, string tag)
{
     if (users == null) return null;
     return users.Where(u => u.Tags.Contains(tag));
}
```

You would call the method like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = data.Users;
IEnumerable<User> cppGroup = users.WithTag("c++");
```

---

If you want to get all the possible tags:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllTags(this IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    if (users == null) return null;
    return users.Select(u => u.Tags).SelectMany(t => t).Distinct();
}
```

---

Finally, if you want to get all the common users for all tags:

```
public static IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<User>> AllCommonTags(this IEnumerable<User> users)
{
     if (users == null) return null;
     return users.AllTags().Select(t => new
     {
         Tag = t, Users = users.WithTag(t)
     }).ToDictionary(ct => ct.Tag, ct => ct.Users);
}
```

You would consume it like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = data.Users;
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<User>> commonTags = users.AllCommonTags();

IEnumerable<User> cppGroup = tags["c++"];
IEnumerable<User> htmlGroup = tags["html"];
```

Comment: Should I import my json file to the code or I can load the string using File.ReadAllText ?

Comment: @user7938276 You can do `string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/json/data.json");`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make this work. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: Is it possible for me to query directly from the main class, something like: SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE TAG >= 2 ?

Comment: When I run I get this error: 

Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__16`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__63`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)