# Is it possible to intersect two jsons?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to make a intersect in c# between two JSONs.

For example, given the next objects and the operation intersect:

```
{
"Property 1" : "Value 1",
"Property 2" : "Value 2",
"Property 3" : "Value 3",
"Property 4" : "Value 4"
}
```

Intersect

```
{
"Property 1" : "Value 1",
"Property 2" : "Value 2",
"Property 6" : "Value 6"
}
```

Should be equal to :

```
{
"Property 1" : "Value 1",
"Property 2" : "Value 2"
}
```

I put a simple json just for clearness, but the json objects could be in any format, complex and simple.

Comment: You said "_trying to make a intersect in c#_", but I think you forgot to add the code you already written

Comment: You could deserialize into a Dictionary<string, string> and do custom comparison logic

Comment: @maccettura missread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to query a json file to find users with two or more tags in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687592/i-want-to-query-a-json-file-to-find-users-with-two-or-more-tags-in-common)

Comment: Deserialize, Intersect, Serialize

Comment: @Sunil I haven't writen any code yet, becouse I think there should be a function or something already done that I am missing

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If you ment, deserialize the Jobject to string and interesct the two strings, it didn't work ;(

Comment: @maccettura How can I deserialize into Dictonary<string,string> it if the json have complex atributes?

Comment: @PabloSalazar well the JSON you posted in your question isnt complex at all.  So if that JSON is _not_ an accurate representation of your data, why would you include it in your question?

Comment: @maccettura I put a simple example just to be clear, the recibing json could be in any format

Comment: It is highly unlikely that there is a general solution for this already out there because it is such an odd request. It is also lacking a lot of details, such as what if `"Property 2"` had a different value in the second JSON? Your best option is probably to write your own implementation of this algorithm. Why are you doing this? Which problem are you trying to solve where this seems like a solution?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen if it has a diferent value it musn't appear in the result json. I am looking for exactly identical preoperty-values.
And yes, it seems there is no solution, I will have to write it myself, thank you anyways :)

Comment: Ah, I think my head exploded at the use of "jsons" I think you meant "objects".

Comment: Devise the rules for intersection on two arbitrary JSON objects, and then implement those rules. Is it possible? Sure. You're a computer programmer; it's possible for you to program a computer to do that.  I don't see an actual *question* here; what's your question?

Comment: I think a problem you might be having is you started with an example that is too complicated.  What is the intersection of `[]` with `{}` ? Both are legal JSON documents, so what is their intersection? Is the intersection of two valid JSON documents also a valid JSON document? If you can't determine the intersection in the simplest cases then you'll never get the complicated cases right.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json to Dictionary and intersect it from there.

I used this json string

```
 string Json1 = @"
{""Property 1"" : ""Value 1"",
""Property 2"" : ""Value 2"",
""Property 3"" : ""Value 3"",
""Property 4"" : ""Value 4""
}";

 string Json2 = @"{
""Property 1"" : ""Value 1"",
""Property 2"" : ""Value 2"",
""Property 6"" : ""Value 6""
}";
 var Result = IntersectedJson(Json1, Json2);
 Console.WriteLine(Result);
 Console.Read();

 public static string IntersectedJson(string Json1, string Json2)
    {
        var Dictionary1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(Json1);
        var Dictionary2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(Json2);
        var result = Dictionary1.Keys.Intersect(Dictionary2.Keys).ToDictionary(t => t, t => Dictionary1[t]);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    }
```

This is the result i got

```
{"Property 1":"Value 1","Property 2":"Value 2"}
```

I am using NewtonSoft.Json to serialize.It should work as long as the property names are unique. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello.
This works as long as the json has simple atributes right?, still, maybe I can use that in the algorithm. 
Thank you!

Comment: Even if they are complex types. aren't you going to intersect them on Keys? why does it matter whats inside the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ, that should have a better performance...

```
        var json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(
            @"{
            'Property 1': 'Value 1',
            'Property 2': 'Value 2',
            'Property 3': 'Value 3',
            'Property 4': 'Value 4'
            }");
        var json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(
            @"{ 
            'Property 1': 'Value 1',
            'Property 2': 'Value 2'
            }");

        // that will do the trick
        var result = json1.Where(x => json2.ContainsKey(x.Key))
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```